# Convert Python script to KV language as a screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have this code in python script and it works just fine. I've been trying to convert into KV so I can implicate it into my application but my attempts were failures. Please help :( the code needed for converting is as follows and it has been coded in python 3.4.4. at the moment it's programmed as an app but I need it as a screen:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.button import Button

    class ScrollViewApp(App):

        def build(self):
            layout1 = GridLayout(cols=6, spacing=10, size_hint=(None, None))
            layout1.bind(minimum_height=layout1.setter('height'),
                         minimum_width=layout1.setter('width'))
            for i in range(200):
                btn = Button(text='student'+str(i), size_hint=(None, None),
                             size=(200, 100))
                layout1.add_widget(btn)
            scrollview1 = ScrollView(bar_width='10dp')
            scrollview1.add_widget(layout1)
            root = GridLayout(cols=1)
            root.add_widget(scrollview1)
            return root

    ScrollViewApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some more things, so you can learn something new. You can ask me questions in comments if there are any. Here you go...

*main.py*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import mainthread


class StudentsScreen(Screen):

    grid = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StudentsScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.create_buttons()

    @mainthread  # slight delay
    def create_buttons(self):
        for i in xrange(200):
            button = StudentButton(text='student %s' % i)
            self.grid.add_widget(button)


class StudentButton(Button):
    pass


class Test(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

*test.kv*:

```
ScreenManager:

    StudentsScreen:
        grid: grid

        ScrollView:
            bar_width: '10dp'

            GridLayout:
                id: grid
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.minimum_width, self.minimum_height
                cols: 6
                spacing: dp(10)


<StudentButton>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: '200dp', '100dp'
```

Comment: hey, thanks for helping me out, i changed the size of the scroll screen abit so i have a bit of space at the top of the screen which i intend to use as a menu bar, any  ideas on how i can go about doing that? @jilgeza

Comment: @Abul You can use ActionBar widget. I see the docs page is down, but if you go to catalog `kivy/uix` and run `actionbar.py`, you will see a demonstration.

Comment: thank you so much i have another issue though, everytime i go back from the screen and re enter (in the same main loop), it will make another set of those buttons. How do i make it not do that?

Comment: @Abul I've edited the code. Changed `on_enter` to `init`.

Comment: @Abul Please mark the answer as answered if it is sufficient.